# MathJax: hide math expression while processing

Tags: javascript, mathjax

Im developing an application that shows a mathematical expression in function of the content of a form.

The webpage show the different states of the expression while its rendering, and I would like to show only the last state.

I have already hidden the mathematical expression while its shown in Tex language while MathJax is rendering.

But there are still two states more:

- *Processing*: The expression is in a bigger font.
- *Typesetted*: The final version, in a smaller font.

Im trying to hide one of them through:

> Stopping *MathJax* before typesetting
>
> **or**
>
> Hide the expression while processing it

Is it possible?

This is the code to create the mathematial expression.

JAVASCRIPT

```
window.UpdateMath = function () {

values = document.getElementsByClassName('level');
arrayvalues = toArray(values);

var formula = "$10 &#92;log (";
for (i = 0; i < arrayvalues.length; i++) {
if (i == 0){
 formula = formula + " 10^{ &#92;frac{" + arrayvalues[i] + "}{10}} ";
}else{
 formula = formula + " + 10^{ &#92;frac{" + arrayvalues[i] + "}{10}} ";
}
}
formula = formula + ")$";

document.getElementById('MathOutput').style.visibility = "hidden";
document.getElementById("MathOutput").innerHTML = formula;

//reprocess the MathOutput Element
MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub,"MathOutput"]);
MathJax.Hub.Queue(
function () {
document.getElementById('MathOutput').style.visibility = "";
}
);
}
})();
```

Full code here:
http://jsfiddle.net/AqDCA/888/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to turn off preprocessor previews and the fast previews.  Try setting your configuration to this

```
  MathJax.Hub.Config({
    "fast-preview": {disabled:true},
    tex2jax: {
      preview: "none",
      inlineMath: [["$","$"],["\\(","\\)"]]
    }
  });
```

This should make things work a bit more like what you want.

Comment: Perfect. Just the thing I wanted :) Thanks!