# Mathjax hide expression while processing

Tags: javascript, jquery, mathjax

I read [MathJax: hide math expression while processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39159953/mathjax-hide-math-expression-while-processing) but it's not solution I expected. I have a HTML file :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var data = {"questions":[{"date":"20170213","tssec":"1486970823","priority":"0","question":"{\"question_type\":\"single\",\"question\":\" Số điểm cực tiểu của hàm số $y = {x^4} - 2{{\\\\rm{x}}^2} + 100$ là:\",\"options\":[\" 1\",\" 3\",\" 2\",\" 0\"],\"correct\":[0]}","question_id":"5","ts":"14:27:30+00"},{"date":"20170213","tssec":"1486970823","priority":"0","question":"{\"question_type\":\"single\",\"question\":\" Giá trị lớn nhất M và giá trị nhỏ nhất m của hàm số $y = {x^3} - 3{x^2} + 3$ trên đoạn [0;3] là:\",\"options\":[\" M = 3 ; m = -1\",\" M = 0; m = 2\",\" M = 6; m = 1\",\" M = 3; m = 1\"],\"correct\":[0]}","question_id":"6","ts":"14:27:30+00"},{"date":"20170213","tssec":"1486970823","priority":"0","question":"{\"question_type\":\"single\",\"question\":\" Đồ thị hàm số $y = \\\\frac{{ - x + 2}}{{x - 1}}$ có các đường tiệm cận là:\",\"options\":[\" Tiệm cận đứng x = -1; tiệm cận ngang y = -1\",\" Tiệm cận đứng y = 1; tiệm cận ngang x = -1\",\" Tiệm cận đứng x = -1; tiệm cận ngang y = 1\",\" Tiệm cận đứng x = 1; tiệm cận ngang y = -1\"],\"correct\":[3]}","question_id":"7","ts":"14:27:30+00"},{"date":"20170213","tssec":"1486970823","priority":"0","question":"{\"question_type\":\"single\",\"question\":\" Hỏi hàm số y = $ - {x^3} + 3{x^2} + 9x$ nghịch biến trên khoảng nào?\",\"options\":[\" (-$\\\\infty $;3)\",\" (-1;3) \",\" ( -$\\\\infty $; -1) và ( 3; +$\\\\infty $) \",\" ( 3; +$\\\\infty $) \"],\"correct\":[1]}","question_id":"8","ts":"14:27:30+00"},{"date":"20170213","tssec":"1486970823","priority":"0","question":"{\"question_type\":\"single\",\"question\":\" Tìm tất cả các giá trị thực của tham số m để hàm số $y = - \\\\frac{1}{3}{x^3} + m{x^2} + mx - 2017$ nghịch biến trên R.\",\"options\":[\" ( -1; 0) \",\" [-1; 0] \",\" ( - $\\\\infty $; -1) $ \\\\cup $ (0; +$\\\\infty $) \",\" ( - $\\\\infty $; -1] $ \\\\cup $ [ 0; +$\\\\infty $) \"],\"correct\":[0]}","question_id":"9","ts":"14:27:30+00"},{"date":"20170213","tssec":"1486970823","priority":"0","question":"{\"question_type\":\"single\",\"question\":\" Tìm tất cả các giá trị thực của tham số m để hàm số của hàm số $y = \\\\frac{{2mx + 1}}{{m - x}}$ trên có giá trị lớn nhất trên đoạn [2; 3] là $ - \\\\frac{1}{3}$.\",\"options\":[\" 1 \",\" -5 \",\" – 2\",\" 0 \"],\"correct\":[3]}","question_id":"10","ts":"14:27:30+00"},{"date":"20170213","tssec":"1486970823","priority":"0","question":"{\"question_type\":\"single\",\"question\":\" Tìm các giá trị thực của tham số m để đường thẳng $\\\\left( d \\\\right):y = x + m - 1$ cắt đồ thị hàm số $y=\\\\frac{2x+1}{x+1}$ tại 2 điểm phân biệt A, B sao cho $AB = 2\\\\sqrt 3 $.\",\"options\":[\" $m = 4 \\\\pm \\\\sqrt {10} $\",\" $m = 2 \\\\pm \\\\sqrt {10} $\",\" $m = 2 \\\\pm \\\\sqrt 3 $\",\" $m = 4 \\\\pm \\\\sqrt 3 $\"],\"correct\":[3]}","question_id":"11","ts":"14:27:30+00"},{"date":"20170213","tssec":"1486970823","priority":"0","question":"{\"question_type\":\"single\",\"question\":\" Tìm m để hàm số $y = {x^3} - 6{x^2} + (m - 1)x + 2016$ đồng biến trên khoảng $\\\\left( {1\\\\;;\\\\; + \\\\infty } \\\\right)$.\\r\\n\",\"options\":[\" $m > 13$\",\" $m = - 13$\",\" $m < 13$\",\" $m \\\\ge 13$\"],\"correct\":[1]}","question_id":"12","ts":"14:27:30+00"},{"date":"20170213","tssec":"1486970823","priority":"0","question":"{\"question_type\":\"single\",\"question\":\" Đồ thị sau đây là đồ thị tương ứng của hàm số nào?\\r\\n\",\"options\":[\" $y = \\\\frac{{x + 2}}{{x + 1}}$\",\" $y = \\\\frac{{ - x - 2}}{{x - 1}}$\",\" $y = \\\\frac{{2 - x}}{{x + 1}}$\",\" $y = \\\\frac{{2 - x}}{{x - 1}}$\"],\"correct\":[3]}","question_id":"3","ts":"14:27:30+00"}]};
  data.questions.map(function(value,index){
    var question = JSON.parse(value.question);
    var id='q'+index;
    $("#content").append('<div id="'+id+'">'+question.question+'</div>');
    $("#"+id).css("visibility","hidden");
    MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub,id]);
    MathJax.Hub.Queue(function(){
      $("#"+id).css("visibility","");
    });
  });
});
var showMath = function(id){
  $("#"+id).css("visibility","");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
      MathJax.Hub.Config({
        tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']]},
        skipStartupTypeset: true,
        showMathMenu: true
      });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" async src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

As you can see it works fine but when I pass `showMath` instead of a anonymous function into queue it still show that ugly unprocessed expression. Can anybody tell me why is that? and if I use a anonymous function, how can I pass variables to it?

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/ for migration tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing showMath on its own won't be helpful since you have to pass the `id` to `showMath`. Luckily, MathJax's APIs cover this use case -- you can pass an array of the function and its parameter.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var data = {"questions":[{"date":"20170213","tssec":"1486970823","priority":"0","question":"{\"question_type\":\"single\",\"question\":\" Số điểm cực tiểu của hàm số $y = {x^4} - 2{{\\\\rm{x}}^2} + 100$ là:\",\"options\":[\" 1\",\" 3\",\" 2\",\" 0\"],\"correct\":[0]}","question_id":"5","ts":"14:27:30+00"},{"date":"20170213","tssec":"1486970823","priority":"0","question":"{\"question_type\":\"single\",\"question\":\" Giá trị lớn nhất M và giá trị nhỏ nhất m của hàm số $y = {x^3} - 3{x^2} + 3$ trên đoạn [0;3] là:\",\"options\":[\" M = 3 ; m = -1\",\" M = 0; m = 2\",\" M = 6; m = 1\",\" M = 3; m = 1\"],\"correct\":[0]}","question_id":"6","ts":"14:27:30+00"},{"date":"20170213","tssec":"1486970823","priority":"0","question":"{\"question_type\":\"single\",\"question\":\" Đồ thị hàm số $y = \\\\frac{{ - x + 2}}{{x - 1}}$ có các đường tiệm cận là:\",\"options\":[\" Tiệm cận đứng x = -1; tiệm cận ngang y = -1\",\" Tiệm cận đứng y = 1; tiệm cận ngang x = -1\",\" Tiệm cận đứng x = -1; tiệm cận ngang y = 1\",\" Tiệm cận đứng x = 1; tiệm cận ngang y = -1\"],\"correct\":[3]}","question_id":"7","ts":"14:27:30+00"},{"date":"20170213","tssec":"1486970823","priority":"0","question":"{\"question_type\":\"single\",\"question\":\" Hỏi hàm số y = $ - {x^3} + 3{x^2} + 9x$ nghịch biến trên khoảng nào?\",\"options\":[\" (-$\\\\infty $;3)\",\" (-1;3) \",\" ( -$\\\\infty $; -1) và ( 3; +$\\\\infty $) \",\" ( 3; +$\\\\infty $) \"],\"correct\":[1]}","question_id":"8","ts":"14:27:30+00"},{"date":"20170213","tssec":"1486970823","priority":"0","question":"{\"question_type\":\"single\",\"question\":\" Tìm tất cả các giá trị thực của tham số m để hàm số $y = - \\\\frac{1}{3}{x^3} + m{x^2} + mx - 2017$ nghịch biến trên R.\",\"options\":[\" ( -1; 0) \",\" [-1; 0] \",\" ( - $\\\\infty $; -1) $ \\\\cup $ (0; +$\\\\infty $) \",\" ( - $\\\\infty $; -1] $ \\\\cup $ [ 0; +$\\\\infty $) \"],\"correct\":[0]}","question_id":"9","ts":"14:27:30+00"},{"date":"20170213","tssec":"1486970823","priority":"0","question":"{\"question_type\":\"single\",\"question\":\" Tìm tất cả các giá trị thực của tham số m để hàm số của hàm số $y = \\\\frac{{2mx + 1}}{{m - x}}$ trên có giá trị lớn nhất trên đoạn [2; 3] là $ - \\\\frac{1}{3}$.\",\"options\":[\" 1 \",\" -5 \",\" – 2\",\" 0 \"],\"correct\":[3]}","question_id":"10","ts":"14:27:30+00"},{"date":"20170213","tssec":"1486970823","priority":"0","question":"{\"question_type\":\"single\",\"question\":\" Tìm các giá trị thực của tham số m để đường thẳng $\\\\left( d \\\\right):y = x + m - 1$ cắt đồ thị hàm số $y=\\\\frac{2x+1}{x+1}$ tại 2 điểm phân biệt A, B sao cho $AB = 2\\\\sqrt 3 $.\",\"options\":[\" $m = 4 \\\\pm \\\\sqrt {10} $\",\" $m = 2 \\\\pm \\\\sqrt {10} $\",\" $m = 2 \\\\pm \\\\sqrt 3 $\",\" $m = 4 \\\\pm \\\\sqrt 3 $\"],\"correct\":[3]}","question_id":"11","ts":"14:27:30+00"},{"date":"20170213","tssec":"1486970823","priority":"0","question":"{\"question_type\":\"single\",\"question\":\" Tìm m để hàm số $y = {x^3} - 6{x^2} + (m - 1)x + 2016$ đồng biến trên khoảng $\\\\left( {1\\\\;;\\\\; + \\\\infty } \\\\right)$.\\r\\n\",\"options\":[\" $m > 13$\",\" $m = - 13$\",\" $m < 13$\",\" $m \\\\ge 13$\"],\"correct\":[1]}","question_id":"12","ts":"14:27:30+00"},{"date":"20170213","tssec":"1486970823","priority":"0","question":"{\"question_type\":\"single\",\"question\":\" Đồ thị sau đây là đồ thị tương ứng của hàm số nào?\\r\\n\",\"options\":[\" $y = \\\\frac{{x + 2}}{{x + 1}}$\",\" $y = \\\\frac{{ - x - 2}}{{x - 1}}$\",\" $y = \\\\frac{{2 - x}}{{x + 1}}$\",\" $y = \\\\frac{{2 - x}}{{x - 1}}$\"],\"correct\":[3]}","question_id":"3","ts":"14:27:30+00"}]};
  data.questions.map(function(value,index){
    var question = JSON.parse(value.question);
    var id='q'+index;
    $("#content").append('<div id="'+id+'">'+question.question+'</div>');
    $("#"+id).css("visibility","hidden");
    MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub,id]);
    MathJax.Hub.Queue([showMath, id]);
  });
});
var showMath = function(id){
  $("#"+id).css("visibility","");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
      MathJax.Hub.Config({
        tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']]},
        skipStartupTypeset: true,
        showMathMenu: true
      });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" async src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.0/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It works correctly.Thanks a lot but can you tell me the difference between MathJax.Hub.Queue([showMath, id]) and MathJax.Hub.Queue(showMath(id)) and MathJax.Hub.Queue(function(){})?

Comment: `MathJax.Hub.Queue(showMath(id))` means that  ` MathJax.Hub.Queue` is called with the return value of `showMath(id)`; since `showMath`'s returns  `undefined` nothing will happen (except that `showMath(id)` is executed of course). In the SO question you referred to, the function did not require an argument; in that  case ` MathJax.Hub.Queue(showMath)` runs the function just fine. To a similar effect, you could use `bind`, e.g., `MathJax.Hub.Queue(showMath.bind(null, id));` but `bind` does not work on IE <9 (which is why MathJax provides an easy API -- it works down to IE6).

Comment: Oh I get it! Thanks